# Facebook Marketing API - Target language

Tags: facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

For the Facebook Marking API (Python) in https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk, I cannot find out how to target users with specific language. For example, I only want to target user who speaks Korean.

Can someone show me how to do this? I can't find any example under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/targeting.

Comment: Answer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search#locale